# Getting rid of a dependency inside a static class

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I need to refactor a project in order to use Autofac. But I'm struggling to try to use it in a service (CrmCustomerService) that has a constructor like this:

```
//...

private readonly CrmService _service;

//...

public CrmCustomerService()
{
    _service = InstantiateCrmIntegrationWebServices();
}

public static CrmService InstantiateCrmIntegrationWebServices()
{
    var service = new CrmService();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigParameter.GetS("webservices.url.CrmIntegrationWebService")))
    {
        service.Url = ConfigParameter.GetS("webservices.url.CrmIntegrationWebService");
    }

    var token = new CrmAuthenticationToken
    {
        AuthenticationType = 0, 
        OrganizationName = "Foo"
    };
    service.CrmAuthenticationTokenValue = token;
    service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ConfigParameter.GetS("crm.UserId"), ConfigParameter.GetS("crm.Password"), ConfigParameter.GetS("crm.Domain"));
    return service;
}
```

How could I inject in the CrmCustomerService constructor the CrmService? It would be enough for the moment if I was able just to tell Autofac to use this method for that dependency but not sure if I could achieve that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Autofac can accept a delegate or lambda expression to be used as a component creator](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/ComponentCreation). This would allow you to encapsulate the creation of the `CrmService` in a lambda expression within the registration of the `CrmService` service.

Using the following cutdown `CrmService` type and associated extracted interface:

```
public interface ICrmService
{
    string Url { get; set; }
}

public class CrmService : ICrmService
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

Then register the `ICrmService` service as follows in your builder configuration:

```
builder.Register<ICrmService>(x =>
{
    var service = new CrmService
    {
        Url = "Get url from config"               
    };
    return service;
});
```

Then inject into your `CrmCustomerService` type as normal.

**Update**
Alternatively, if you don't want to extract an interface for `CrmService` just do the following:

```
builder.Register<CrmService>(x =>
{
    var service = new CrmService
    {
        Url = "Get url from config"               
    };
    return service;
});
```

Comment: Thanks @LongboatHarry, if I couldn't create an Interface on the CrmService would it be possible to bind it using the AsSelf()?

Comment: Sure - its possible to tell AutoFac to resolve against a concrete service. See update.